# Tallit with Wool Atara

Tags: halacha, minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, tallit-gadol, stringency-chumrah

The only tallit I know of that has an all wool atara is the Beit Yosef Tallit, which is marketed for Sephardim. Is there a specific source for this or is it simply being *machmir* to wear an all-wool tallit?

[image: All-white tallit labeled "Beit Yosef" in Hebrew.]

Answer (score 9):

The [Aruch HaShulchan - Siman 8 Seif 10](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%AA) - who to my knowledge was not a Sefardi - writes:

> וכן נכון לעשות שלא יהיה בהטלית רק צמר
>   And so it is correct to do: to make the tallit only out of wool.

It is interesting that Ashkenazim do not seem to be particular about this, yet Sefardim are!

Comment: Because Ashkanazim have whom to rely on http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=922&st=&pgnum=96 . Also ,I have not seen A sefardi Jew who has a silver atara prob for the same reason.

Comment: On the other hand, the Wikipedia photo for R' Eliyahu shows him wearing a silver atarah, unless the photo is mis-attributed.

Comment: Conversely, the Atara is a kishut and not considered integral to the beged. Therefore, even IF they agree with the psak of the Aruch Hashulchan, the atara is tafel and isn't considered "part of the tallit."

Comment: Funny thing is that Aruch Hashulchan's family used to be Sfardim. I think Benibiteshi was the original name. I can add as a side point the benefit for having a wool attara is no-one mixes mine up with theirs!

Comment: Gershon, my tallitot are all made of wool (except for the corner linings on my tallitot ketanot)