# Silver Atarah for Tallit

Tags: tallit-gadol, provenance, jewelry

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14689/tallit-with-wool-atara): What is the origin of the silver atarot worn by some [typically married] men on their Shabbat tallitot?

Answer (score 1):

See the [Aruch Hashulchan](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0007_L2), who says this was started as a way to beautify the mitzvah of tzizis ie. ze keili v'anveyhu.

He does take issue with this practice though, as the ikkar mitzvah (main part of the Mitzva) is on the middle part of the tallis, not the head, as the mitzvah is levisha (wearing) and not the head wrapping ie, ittuf.

Thus, some wanting to be stringent will have a line of embroidery or silver running along the back width wise.

> וגם יש שעושים עטרה של כסף בראש הטלית המונח על הראש. ‏
>
> ואינו כדאי, דבזה נראה דהעיקר הוא מה שעל הראש, ובאמת העיקר הוא מה שעל הגוף. ‏
>
> ולכן יש נוהגים מטעם זה לשום גם עטרה של כסף באמצע הטלית (עיין בארצות החיים). אבל גם זה אינו כדאי, ורבים וגדולים מונעים את עצמו מזה. וכן נכון לעשות שלא יהיה בהטלית רק צמר, ומה לכסף וזהב בטלית? ‏
>
> והאריז''ל ודאי לא עשה כן, דאם כן לא היה אפשר להפכו.) ‏)

Comment: Why is the brachah "l'**hitateif** b'tzitzit" then?

Comment: good question, i think the biur halocha (i dont remember exactly where) answers this question. look as well in the Maaseh Rav of the Vilna Gaon, whos holds that one does not nned atifas yishmaeilim when making the brocha.

Comment: There is certainly a machloket about the definition of ittuf. The way that I learned to put on a tallit does not use atifat yishmaelim, however it is still called ittuf. Furthermore, see the comments on http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40569/may-one-wear-a-tallit-gadol-with-all-four-corners-in-front/44237#44237, where the issue of ittuf is discussed.